# appsettings.json in Deploy folder not updated to show production connection strings

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am developing a **.Net Core web application** using a fully patched version of **Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3**.

In the root of my application, I have the standard *appsettings.json* file and a appsettings.Production.json file.   The *appsettings.Production.json* has different values for some of the attributes.    The *appsettings.Production.json* file appears nested correctly in Visual Studio's solution explorer.

I have a Configuration Manager entry called *Production*.  I have a File System publish job setup also called *Production* which pushes files into a folder named */Deploy*

When I publish, the *appsettings.json* file is pushed into the */Deploy* folder but it just contains the default values instead of the ones in *appsettings.Production.json*.    No matter what I do I can not get the production values to push into the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Have you found a solution, I am having the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appsettings.Production.json` should be published as a separate file, it does not replace content of `appsettings.json` during publishing.

You should add appsettings.Production.json into `publishOptions` section in `project.json` file:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.Production.json",
    ...
  ]
},
```

and add it when construct `ConfigurationBuilder` :

```
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
```

Comment: I am guessing you meant, project.json.

Comment: So, that's weird.   It means you would push your production database connection string, etc. into  every environment?   Seems like a bit of a security flaw?  With web.config transformations, only the environment's particular settings were pushed to that environment.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code you should consider not to use appsettings for security configs. Instead, use environment variables or user secrets for that

Comment: @eat-sleep-code another option is do not put appsettings.Development.json into source control, and do not publish, but insert the file later/have the file only exist in production. (The optional: true will ignore if it is missing in other environments, but load and override when it is there). 

But yeah, environments such as Azure already have built in support for overriding using environment variables.

Comment: What about a connection string? Do I really publish every environment transformation and figure out which one to use at run time based on a OS Level environment variable? That seems like a huge step backward. What happened to transforming just what I need on build?